# sink() is not called in combine swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have LocationManager class that works well. This is part of LocationManager class.

```
  var headingDegree = PassthroughSubject<Double, Never>()

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    headingDegree.send(-newHeading.magneticHeading)
  }
```

`headingDegree` is the value I want to send to my ViewModel. I debugged it to make sure it has correct values, and it does.

So, in my view model,

```
class CompassViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
 @Published var degree: Double = 0.0
 @State var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()

 func update() {
    LocationManager.shared.headingDegree.sink {
      self.degree = $0
    }
    .store(in: &cancellable)
  }
```

I sinked my `headingDegree`. This is the part that brings my problems. If I put breakpoints in `update()` function, `self.degree = $0` is never called.

This is how my View looks like.

```
struct CompassView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: CompassViewViewModel

  init(viewModel: CompassViewViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
  }

 var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Text("aa")
        .font(.footnote)
    }
      .onAppear {
        self.viewModel.update()
    }
  }
}
```

Could you tell me why my sink() is not called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed `@State var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()` to `private var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()` and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

in swiftUI1, viewDidLoad in UIHostingcontroller isn't called.

---

when using combine, with UIKit, subscribing (Sink) in viewDidload, didn't work, instead, subscribe in viewDidAppear