# Combine `.sink` not being called when observing Singleton

Tags: ios, swift, combine

When using Combine to observe changes in a Singleton, the change seems to not be recognised. I have tried to make the Singleton an `@ObservableObject` and adding `self?.objectWillChange.send()` but other than that I have no clue what to do.

[This problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59712847/sink-is-not-called-in-combine-swift) looked similar, however I am already doing what the solution suggests.

In my understanding this should print "CHECK" after "MODDED" every 3 seconds, but only "MODDED" is printed:

```
class MREViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    @Published var ownUser: MREUser
    
    init() {
        ownUser = MREUserService.shared.ownUser
        setupBindings()
    }
    
    func setupBindings() {
        MREUserService.shared.$ownUser
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] user in
                print("CHECK")
                self?.objectWillChange.send()
                self?.ownUser = user
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

// doesn't work with or without this view that will eventually be used
struct ViewSwiftUI: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: MREViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.ownUser.userName)
    }
}

class MREUserService: ObservableObject {
    
    static var shared: MREUserService = MREUserService()
    
    @Published var ownUser = MREUser(userName: "initialised")
    
    var timer: Timer?
    
    init() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: true) { timer in
            self.objectWillChange.send()
            self.ownUser.userName = "\(Date())"
            print("MODDED: \(self.ownUser.userName)")
        }
    }
}

class MREUser {
    var _id = UUID().uuidString
    var userName: String
    
    init(userName: String) {
        self.userName = userName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does `MREUser` really need to be a class ? It's already a property of the `MREUserService` singleton, so you won't have an issue with a struct even if you need a [shared mutable state](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10)

With:

```swift
class MREUserService: ObservableObject {
    
    static var shared: MREUserService = MREUserService()
    
    @Published var ownUser = MREUser(userName: "initialised")
    
    var timer: Timer?
    
    init() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: true) { timer in
            self.ownUser.userName = "\(Date())"
            print("MODDED: \(self.ownUser.userName)")
        }
    }
}

struct MREUser {
    var _id = UUID().uuidString
    var userName: String
    
    init(userName: String) {
        self.userName = userName
    }
}
```

I get :

> CHECK
>
> MODDED: 2023-04-23 17:32:59 +0000
>
> CHECK
>
> MODDED: 2023-04-23 17:33:02 +0000
>
> CHECK
>
> MODDED: 2023-04-23 17:33:05 +0000
>
> CHECK